# How to make option selected using select binding of knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

I want to select default option in select box.

I have tried many solution but did not succeed.

1. I have array of of number of options let's say processChannels.
2. Then I have created select options by assigning my option array to select dropdown.
3. Now I have one value which stored in one variable processTaskActor.

I want to make processTaskActor value selected to select dropdown.

Below is my code

```
<div>
        <select data-bind="options: processChannels,
            optionsText: 'propertyText',
            optionsValue: $data,
            value: processTaskActor,
            valueUpdate: 'input' ">
         </select>

         <div data-bind="with:processTaskActor">
            <div data-bind="text: propertyText">
         </div>

    </div>
    <script>
        var ViewModel = function(first, last) {

        self.processChannels = [
        {
          "propertyName": "Initiator",
          "propertyType": "User",
          "propertyValue": "",
          "propertyText": "Initiator"
        },
        {
          "propertyName": "Initiator",
          "propertyType": "User",
          "propertyValue": "",
          "propertyText": "Initiator Reject pruchase"
        },
        {
          "propertyName": "Initiator",
          "propertyType": "User",
          "propertyValue": "",
          "propertyText": "Initiator Purchase Approved"
        },
        {
          "propertyName": "Initiator",
          "propertyType": "User",
          "propertyValue": "",
          "propertyText": "Initiator Purchase approved high amount"
        },
        {
          "propertyName": "Manager",
          "propertyType": "User",
          "propertyValue": "",
          "propertyText": "Manager Approval"
        },
        {
          "propertyName": "Finance manager",
          "propertyType": "User",
          "propertyValue": "",
          "propertyText": "Finance manager Approve High amount"
        }
        ];

        self.processTaskActor = ko.observable({
          "propertyName": "Finance manager",
          "propertyType": "User",
          "propertyValue": "",
          "propertyText": "Finance manager Approve High amount"
        });
    };

    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
    </script>
```

I Haven't use knockout much.

Please help me to resolve issue.

Sorry for bad english

Comment: looks like it's working fine to me? either that or i'm missing the problem that you are describing. http://jsfiddle.net/munavf16/

Comment: nop not correct yet binding is perfect.
But i want to make "Finance manager Approve High amount" default selected at time of page load. 
got it ?

Sorry for bad explaination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `self.processTaskActor = ko.observable(self.processChannels[5]);`

Comment: looks good :)
But i want to user array object only to reduce computations.
Is it possible ?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't think I follow your question.

Comment: fine. your answer looks good but not working with my system :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to make your processTaskActor an observable and processChannels an observableArray.

```
self.processTaskActor = ko.observable();
self.processChannels = ko.observableArray...
```

Then you can search in the observable array for the exact object you want. Before you were creating a new object with the same values.

```
var processTaskActor = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.processChannels(), function (process) {
    return process.propertyName === "Finance manager" &&
           process.propertyText === "Finance manager Approve High amount";
});
self.processTaskActor(processTaskActor);
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/otdsx21n/1/):